# Can we authenticate a user in MVC like this?? If not whats the issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       if (AuthenticateUser(model))`enter code here`
        {
             return View ('HomePage')
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I just need to restrict a usr to go to some page directly. If there is some problem in this solution then How can we use Authentication filters to authenticate a perticular action ??

Mudit

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET authentication, you can apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to an action or controller. This will require users to be logged in before they have access to the action.